# IOS Table View + TextView in a UITableView Cell

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, textview

I have a static table view with 3 sections and a row in each section.

For each row, I have it setup to be 150 talk in the heightForRowAtIndexPath.

Then on a tap of the row, I have it setup to expand to the height of the device.

All of that works great.

In the expanded row is a textView. When the user selects the textview, the keyboard pops up and pushes the top of the row off screen for a second and then the tableview seems to catch itself and bring it back down to be visible. How can I make sure that it doesnt do that because it looks buggy from the users POV.

Comment: can you elaborate more what you want to do ?

Comment: @KKRocks I would like the the table cell with the textView subview to keep stay in place and not move too far up and then have to readjust back down. Thanks for asking!

Comment: @AnkitKapasi...I need to implement same...Please update your answer here.